# Can't receive e-mail from external server

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I'm trying to make my email server.
I used [this](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/#postfix) tutorial.
      - I can send message (Yeah !)
      - They are chffred by SSL (Yeah )

But ... I can't receive email from Google by exemple.
If I send me a mail theses mails :
      - **frank@mymail.fr** to **frank@gmail.com** -> WORKS !
      - **frank@mymail.fr** to **frank@mymail.fr**   -> WORKS !
      - **frank@gmail.com** to **frank@mymail.fr** -> **DON'T WORKS** !

Thants what my Google mail answer me :

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     frank@mymail.fr

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mymail.fr by mx00.1and1.fr. [212.227.15.41].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable


----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
    h=mime-version:in-reply-to:references:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
    bh=IlKfOX0KYoDfYUXp8/X+EcGy/yIoCvXdBvNrR6gqetc=;
    b=o6JxDg2ABmaBWdTQXyoz72d2irysBluYjIiK/1lxPqEUBXoqEQqjGfsk2uEl1v6vMx
     oYq5+BzVeB6daNg1SQ748GnIJAWlOtfuIWC8q3gb3aex/cTvk7OXoI6BOb1LoUWWIg7X
     gTQ5Pjxv1yylfH9op/luNbt5nCyJ1qldOCm/B7oqBV4HBsFXH8iC8Dkk8u+U+xoNAeeT
     Q/CoNyZ0haQTi2CFTA0Bh+GtcUTEsbMQMwt17KNYXWCqTFpINnij9JttvCj+98AXG1xV
     RLDqb01KfW8DlA8eh7ud3l6KvQ4Ci0SrLEaex+xX4MU3HUsQECvH/r9j1tC2eLfVC4zk
     gznw==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
    h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:in-reply-to:references:from:date
     :message-id:subject:to;
    bh=IlKfOX0KYoDfYUXp8/X+EcGy/yIoCvXdBvNrR6gqetc=;
    b=AekB77GUGjcBJAdXN8Ac31XFpeCj4GCqfV/RwTi7FCoEmuaYMzZLotfjbzJCzx5hcb
     QLRvxzKOWNKTVSqxKATptMFlK4rTElk8ykXd0BPvWHwXiNc/M8UWZ8d/+ovdOp5gBg8S
     7nSujwiFfXbgs+rMWUt8Hs+QhQdSr1uYcPYf/W/6SqYb+lJVEqCZaCRXYORUDLW5JcoO
     IcZtKqVHIDQ828qnjGa9tTjxER42/BvQ/Uplvrm60pQxlROd2H7QatnosAKmzt2SezoR
     q3krngcaBOQcC9+Gm1vMFpodSBz6PkwjxkknmSsNhHGVKXIs/B14Ddho/1EVEGNRDTQ4
     It6g==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tIkdkxHQtmRkE0V1yf6xxVVng/qcvvQ8zwrU1NHBzX73b/NkU8qqGvMwIf4VuBpLjp24jwQRQeqH6RXjw==
X-Received: by 10.107.23.133 with SMTP id 127mr2991151iox.186.1466676032747;
 Thu, 23 Jun 2016 03:00:32 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.107.170.132 with HTTP; Thu, 23 Jun 2016 03:00:32 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <a7452923c69a9807e8c00b09d42300fa.squirrel@webmail.mymail.fr>
References: <a7452923c69a9807e8c00b09d42300fa.squirrel@webmail.mymail.fr>
From: Frank Duval <frank@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 12:00:32 +0200
Message-ID: <CALdOknvtLzU0vZoQKU1xJdepsrik0LXT9zOtprDxcd_2YGDsgg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: azdazd
To: frank@mymail.fr
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=94eb2c05a56aeebd690535ef1fa2

test message
```

lol
Have you got an idea to help me please ?
Thats my /etc/hostname :

```
mail.mymail.fr
```

Thats my /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
127.0.0.1 mail.mymail.fr
```

And that's my /etc/postfix/main.cf :

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.cer
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mymail.fr
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost.mymail.fr, mail.mymail.fr, mymail.fr, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

To help you to solve me this problem, know that if i send a message like this :
      - **frank@gmail.com** to **frank@mail.mymail.fr**   -> **I DON'T HAVE ANY ERROR FROM GOOGLE !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update DNS settings : change my MX-record. It was my host one and i set it to mymail.fr and mail.mymail.fr